# CSS Fade In - Fade Out Animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I want the .username text to fade it at 3 seconds and fade out at 4.5 seconds. How do I do that? If you know the answer please provide the entire code.

```
.video{
    position:relative;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    src: url(\fonts\Century Gothic.ttf);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.username{
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:60px;
    x-overflow:hidden;
    y-overflow:hidden;
    top:182px;
    left:735px;
    font-size:50px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: Century Gothic; 
}
```

Comment: hello. insert your html pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this in your css:

```
.username {
   /* you can add these to your existing class or a new one */
   opacity: 0;
   animation: fadeinout 7.5s ease-in-out 1;
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
   /* 40% would be 3secs, 60% 4.5 secs */
   40% {
      opacity: 1;
   }

   60% {
      opacity: 0;
   }
}
```